# python/Pandas merge two data frames and return on the rows containing NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Is it possible to use merge to df's, df1 and df2, to return only the rows that are Nan in df2? an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'X1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
        'X2': ['meow', 'bark', 'moo', 'squeak', 'cheep']}

data2 = {'X1': ['A', 'B', 'F', 'D', 'E'], 
         'X3': ['cat', 'dog', 'frog', 'mouse', 'chick']}

#df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'age', 'preTestScore', 
'postTestScore'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

pd.merge(df, df2, how ='left', on = 'X1')
```

This returns

```
X1   X2     X3
A   meow    cat
B   bark    dog
C   moo NaN
D   squeak  mouse
E   cheep   chick
```

I want a result that looks like:

```
X1   X2     X3
C   moo NaN
```

I have tried every combination of merge that I can think of but I can't get it.
I know I can achieve the result with lots of manipulations to the merged df, but i was hoping there was a simple efficient answer

Comment: Do you need `merge`? Will `df[~df.X1.isin(df2.X1)]` work?

Comment: @student! Ha! that's what I was looking for! I didn't think I could use isin on a df column like that! Thanks!

Comment: Great that it worked. `Happy Coding`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using `isnull` and `any` with your result to filter it

```
s=pd.merge(df, df2, how ='left', on = 'X1')
s[s.isnull().any(1)]
Out[185]: 
  X1   X2   X3
2  C  moo  NaN
```

Comment: thanks for that. It gives me another option to use besides students above. I wonder which method is the most efficient time wise

Comment: @MickHawkes this work for multiple column match if you need to match two key , I recommend merge rather than Isin